# What's causing this php define() method to not function?

Tags: php, constants, zen-cart

I'm building a site using Zen Cart and I've changed a define() in a .php file.  Whatever I've done has stopped the function of the program and I can't figure out why.

The only elements I've eliminated are the list tags and the "strong" tags.  Are they somehow essential to defining the constant?

The first is my edit, the second is the stock method (I broke them up like that to search for my errors):

```
define('EMAIL_TEXT', 'You are now registered with our little buying group and have account privileges on this site.' . "\n\n" . 

'Please remember that you can order as many or as few items as you like but if we as a group do not reach case amounts then we can't bring the item in.' . "\n\n" . 

'Please also remember that produce prices vary day to day and week to week.  The prices listed on this site are estimates only.  Expect the final cost to reflect these small fluctuations.  Before I place an order I will send out a group email that will mention any particularly egregious price hikes.' . "\n\n" . 

'You will need to pick up your items from my house in a timely manner.  I can't be held responsible for lettuce wilting in my garage while you're skiing at Liberty all weekend.' . "\n\n" . 

'I'm glad you joined us.  The more people we get, the more produce we should be able to order and the more we order the more I can negotiate better pricing.' . "\n\n" . 

'Here's to eating organic!' . "\n\n" );


define('EMAIL_TEXT', 'You are now registered with our store and have account privileges:  With your account, you can now take part in the <strong>various services</strong> we have to offer you. Some of these many services include:' . "\n\n<ul>" . 

'<li><strong>Order History</strong> - View the details of orders you have completed with us.' . "\n\n" . 

'<li><strong>Permanent Cart</strong> - Any products added to your online cart remain there until you remove them, or check them out.' . "\n\n" . 

'<li><strong>Address Book</strong> - We can deliver your products to an address other than yours! This is perfect to send birthday gifts direct to the birthday-person themselves.' . "\n\n" . 

'<li><strong>Products Reviews</strong> - Share your opinions on our products with other customers.' . "\n\n</ul>");
```

Comment: When you are concatenated strings, make sure to use the quotes instead of an apostrophe.  so "." instead of '."

Comment: I'm just mimicking the stock example.  That's how they have it and it's working fine ...  In their code, the quotes are only surrounding the line break.

Comment: You mis-use the `define()`. You shouldn't store such a huge amount of text in a constant, which it will stay in memory once you defined it till script ends. You probably want to use a variable instead.

Comment: According to [link](http://www.php.net/language.operators.string) the concatenation operator is '.'

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Is mine so much bigger that the stock message works where mine won't?

Comment: The error is you didn't escape your string properly.

Comment: For reference: You should look into an editor that does syntax highlighting -- it would help make issues like this stand out better.  (Look at how SO colored your code, for example.  Once strings stop being string-colored and keywords stop being keyword-colored, it's a safe bet your quotes have gotten mucked up.)  For Windows, Notepad++ is pretty decent.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been using Sublime Text for everything else and I'm sure they do it.  I was editing this file directly on the server though - probably a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the extra apostrophe in the following line that is terminating the definition early:

```
'Here's to eating organic
```

You need to escape the second apostrophe - simply change it to:

```
'Here\'s to...
```

Edit: There are some others too, such as:

```
'I'm...
```

should be

```
'I\'m...
```

Alternatively reformat the string as follows as I think you'll agree it is more legible and there is less of the concatenation:

```
"I'm ... \n\n".
"Here's to organic\n\n".
...
```

Comment: You, sir or madam, are my hero.  I knew it was something like this that my tired mind wasn't seeing.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on formatting the string.  I'm new to php and html so I'm just trying to follow what the stock pages are doing.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The following will be of great use with understanding how you can format strings in PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php